# DATE_FORMAT returning null

Tags: mysql, datetime

I'm trying to get a datetime column from my table using a simple `SELECT` statement, but I want the datetime without seconds.

The datetime column is formatted as `10/21/2013 3:19:33 PM`.

My query is `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(creationdate, '%m-%d%Y %l:%i %p') AS 'Creation Date' FROM processes;`

When I run this query, it returns all `NULL` values. I've double and triple checked, and the column cells do hold datetime values.

However, when I run `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m-%d%Y %l:%i %p) AS 'Creation Date' FROM processes;` I get the current date with correct formatting.

What could cause this?

Comment: What is the datatype for the creationdate field?

Comment: There are typos in your query like missed ' used date in column name and missed - in format **SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m-%d-%Y %l:%i %p') AS `Creation_date`**

Comment: @jeff it's a datetime datatype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`creationdate` must not be of type datetime if it is formatted `10/21/2013 3:19:33 PM` by default.

> The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html

Comment: You're right, I had a case of the Friday brain going on! That column is a varchar datatype. I used `DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(CreationDate, '%m/%d/%Y %l:%i:%s %p'), '%m-%d-%Y %l:%i %p')` and it's working as expected.